# Difference between return and return false

Tags: javascript, return

Let's say in a javascript function I have:

```
function myfunction (x) {
    if (x===0) {
         return false; //return;
    };
    //some code
};
```

Is there a difference between `return` or `return false`?

I'm asking because someone advised me to use just return (and he do not explained why).

I'm using it for exit the function without doing nothing more. In this simple example I could use `if (x!==0) {};` but in longer function maybe (tell me if I'm wrong) is not a good idea to have nested if statement.

Comment: `return` returns `undefined` (or `void 0`) (void), while `return false` returns exactly `false` (boolean). Both are **falsy** (https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Glossary/Falsy) values, but they actually are different. In your case, anyway, there is no difference whatsoever, it largely depends on the usage of the function, which will still likely work as intended in most of the cases (if not all the cases)

Comment: If you just want to exit the function, it doesn't matter at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just consider this code

```
function myFunc(){
  return; // exists function and returns `undefined`
}
const myVar = myFunc() // myVar === undefined
```

and with `false`

```
function myFunc(){
  return false; // exists function and returns `false`
}
const myVar = myFunc() // myVar === false
```

in both caes you this will be same:

```
if (!myFunc()) { console.log('this gets executed if falsy value is passed') }
```

So they are almost the same for this use case (note that if you make any other kind of comparison with `===` it is different story), and which one should you prefer to use?

I would recommend always return something, in this case `false` because if your function doesn't have `return` statement then it will always return `undefined`. So for sake of easier debugging, it's better to return `false` rather than `undefined`, because you will imminently know that return statement was indeed executed, while with `undefined` you have 1 more step to check.

Answer (score 2):

`return false` returns `false`

`return` returns `undefined` (which is `falsey`)

For most use cases it does not really matter, however if you check their types:

```
typeof undefined   //returns "undefined"
typeof false       //returns "boolean"
```

it's just different type.

Moreover:

```
undefined === false   //identity check returns false
undefined == false    //equality returns true
```

I can't find a reason to prefer one over another.

Answer (score 1):

considering

```
var value = myfunction(0)
```

`value` would equal `false` if you used return false. otherwise it would remain "undefined' if you used an "empty" return